# BootStrap Tabpanel does not show tab-content

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

My tabpanel seems to be linked properly to my tab-content, however it does not show the tab-content when I change tabs. How can I fix this?

```
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#cust" aria-controls="cust" role="tab" data-toggle="pill">Customers</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#sales" aria-controls="sales" role="tab" data-toggle="pill">Sales</a></li>
    </ul>

 <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="cust">
        This option is for those who want to work with angular offline, or those who want to host the angular files on their own servers.
  </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="sales">
        lkjdlkfjlkdlkfj  ldjfldjfljdlkdjf ljlkdjlkjlkdjf 
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It perfectly works for me, please check required js files(bootstrap.min.js) were loaded or not

Comment: So when you click on the 'sales' tab, the content changes and the 'nav-pills' switches to the sales tab?

Comment: Yes it works fine,but i have included bootstrap.min.css in general way.

Comment: It seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vs4kfu6z/ ... As @Ramkee suggests: Check your loading of JavaScript files. Bootstrap requires jQuery, so you have to load jQuery before Bootstrap!

Comment: Thanks guys, it was my bootstrap files.